# Thumb create in Yii2 gives an error

Tags: php, yii2

I want to create a thumb but am getting this error:

> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
>   Class 'Imagine\Image\ManipulatorInterface' not found

I don't know from where i can get this? I used [yii2-imagine](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-imagine) but didn't find any `ManipulatorInterface` class.

**controller file:**

```
<?php
namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Employee;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use yii\imagine\Image; // this is where i used Image class

public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Employee();
    $model->added_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'avatar');

        if(!empty($model->file)) {
            $imageName = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
            $model->file->saveAs('uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension);
            $model->avatar = $imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
            $file = 'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
            Image::thumbnail($file, 200, 200)->save('uploads/thumb/', ['quality' => 80]);
        }
        if($model->save()){
            $this->redirect(\Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('employee'));
        }
    }
    else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' =>  $model
            ]);
    }
}
?>
```

Image class file is in `\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\imagine` folder and `ManipulatorInterface` is in `\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\imagine\Image`folder

**Image.php**

```
<?php
namespace yii\Imagine;
class Image extends BaseImage
{
}
?>
```

**BaseImage.php**

```
<?php

namespace yii\imagine;

use Yii;
use imagine\Image\Box;
use imagine\Image\Color;
use imagine\Image\ImageInterface;
use imagine\Image\ImagineInterface;
use imagine\Image\ManipulatorInterface;
use imagine\Image\Point;
use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;
use yii\base\InvalidParamException;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

class BaseImage
{
    public static function thumbnail($filename, $width, $height, $mode = 'outbound')
    {
        $box = new Box($width, $height);
        $img = static::getImagine()->open(Yii::getAlias($filename));

        if (($img->getSize()->getWidth() <= $box->getWidth() && $img->getSize()->getHeight() <= $box->getHeight()) || (!$box->getWidth() && !$box->getHeight())) {
            return $img->copy();
        }

        $img = $img->thumbnail($box, $mode);

        // create empty image to preserve aspect ratio of thumbnail
        $thumb = static::getImagine()->create($box, new Color('FFF', 100));

        // calculate points
        $size = $img->getSize();

        $startX = 0;
        $startY = 0;
        if ($size->getWidth() < $width) {
            $startX = ceil($width - $size->getWidth()) / 2;
        }
        if ($size->getHeight() < $height) {
            $startY = ceil($height - $size->getHeight()) / 2;
        }

        $thumb->paste($img, new Point($startX, $startY));

        return $thumb;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'd say you have a namespace issue, but without code it's hard to help you. Can you paste in your question the relevant code?

Comment: what should i post ?

Comment: The php code which throws this error

Comment: ok i will post the code with more detail

Comment: also tried this `http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/757/how-to-use-imagine-crop-thumb-effects-for-images-on-yii2/` but not working this

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I try 'composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.0"' after that I try 'composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-imagine' again and it's work for me. Hope it helps you too

Comment: You know Why have to install composer-asset-plugin? I am getting the OP error after install composer how is explain in the official docs

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

1) copy imagine to your vendor

```
`pathA: "vendor/Imagine/Draw...."`
```

2) add a alias into `config.php`

```
'components' => [
],

 ....

'aliases'=>[
    '@Imagine'=>'@vendor/Imagine', //this should correspond to pathA above
 ],

 ....

'params' => [
 ],
```

3) check `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php`
config it like this

```
return array(
    ...

    'yii\\imagine\\' => array($vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine'),

    ...

);
```

4) copy yii-imagine into yiisoft

```
pathB:"vendor/yiisoft/yii-imagine"
```

then you can use it .

Answer (score -2):

I have resolved to set path in `extensions.php` under the `yiisoft` folder.

Just follow 2 steps:

1. Open `extensions.php`
2. On the bottom of the file add

```
  'yiisoft/yii2-imagine' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'yiisoft/yii2-imagine',
    'version' => '~2.0.0',
    'alias' => 
    array (
      '@yii/imagine' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine',
      '@Imagine/Image' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/Imagine/Image',
      '@Imagine/Gd' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/Imagine/Gd',
      '@Imagine/Draw' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/Imagine/Draw',
      '@Imagine/Effects' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/Imagine/Effects',
      '@Imagine/Exception' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/Imagine/Exception',
      '@Imagine/Filter' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/Imagine/Filter',
      '@Imagine/Gmagick' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/Imagine/Gmagick',
      '@Imagine/Imagick' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/Imagine/Imagick',
      '@Imagine/resources' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/Imagine/resources',
    ),
  ),
```

So my `extensions.php` looks like

```
<?php

$vendorDir = dirname(__DIR__);

return array (
  'yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer',
    'version' => '2.0.6.0',
    'alias' => 
    array (
      '@yii/swiftmailer' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer',
    ),
  ),
  'yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap',
    'version' => '2.0.6.0',
    'alias' => 
    array (
      '@yii/bootstrap' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap',
    ),
  ),
  'yiisoft/yii2-debug' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'yiisoft/yii2-debug',
    'version' => '2.0.6.0',
    'alias' => 
    array (
      '@yii/debug' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-debug',
    ),
  ),
  'yiisoft/yii2-gii' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'yiisoft/yii2-gii',
    'version' => '2.0.5.0',
    'alias' => 
    array (
      '@yii/gii' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-gii',
    ),
  ),
  'yiisoft/yii2-faker' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'yiisoft/yii2-faker',
    'version' => '2.0.3.0',
    'alias' => 
    array (
      '@yii/faker' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-faker',
    ),
  ),
  'yiisoft/yii2-imagine' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'yiisoft/yii2-imagine',
    'version' => '~2.0.0',
    'alias' => 
    array (
      '@yii/imagine' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine',
      '@Imagine/Image' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/Imagine/Image',
      '@Imagine/Gd' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/Imagine/Gd',
      '@Imagine/Draw' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/Imagine/Draw',
      '@Imagine/Effects' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/Imagine/Effects',
      '@Imagine/Exception' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/Imagine/Exception',
      '@Imagine/Filter' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/Imagine/Filter',
      '@Imagine/Gmagick' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/Imagine/Gmagick',
      '@Imagine/Imagick' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/Imagine/Imagick',
      '@Imagine/resources' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/Imagine/resources',
    ),
  ),
);
```